# Summary in search results show meaningless strings for ppt files

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, search-results, search-express

I have a few powerpoint files that display strange strings into their summary results in the search results page.

For example for one document i see:

> …
>   **9dac618c-c4b7-40c2-8601-0d42a3200557,4;a514988a-d921-461d-837a-3b0cc8861300,6**
>   … From the main menu go to …

The bold letters mean nothing to me - when searched within the powerpoint document they don't appear anywhere. If I open the ppt with notepad++ and search for the string, I get to a tag called "LongProp" within "LongProperties" which does contain the strings (along with 40 more of the same kind).

My question - is there a way to exclude these strings from being indexed. I can't find a crawled property with 'long' in it to match it with the ExcludeFromSummary property. I also tried to delete the  tag from notepad++ but the file doesn't open anymore.

I am using sharepoint foundation with search server express.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your input! Yesterday I actually found where the problem is coming from. Using SPManager I found that there is a property for my files, called **WorkflowChangePath** which contains the exact same strings. I guess it puts some kind of identifier for what workflows have run on this file.
I added it to the **ExcludeFromSummary** managed property to remove it from the search descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rule to the xsl of the core results web part to check if it's .ppt file, and if it is, hide the whole index (assuming it doesn't show anything important) :)